# How to pull data from a SQL Query based on data/id relationship. Using ASP.net WebMatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I'm using ASP.net WebMatrix

**I have a sql query which looks like this:**

```
var queryformdata = db.Query("SELECT * FROM document_data WHERE doc_id = @0", 1534);

doc_id      field_data      field_name
----------  ----------      ----------
1534        John            f_name
1534        61st Street     f_address
```

**And input fields which look like this:**

```
<input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" value="" />
<input type="text" id="f_address" name="f_address" value="" />
```

I want the value of "John" to appear for f_name 
and
"61st Street" to appear for f_address

I know the value of field_data, but don't know how to pull that from the query without doing a separate query for every input field. I found a C# function called .Select() but can't get it to work. Here is what I tried:

```
@{
    DataRow[] foundRows;
    foundRows = queryformdata.Select("field_name LIKE 'f_name'");                
}
<input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" value="@foundRows.field_data" />
```

That gives me the error: Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Can someone help me figure out how to make this work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@{
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = queryformdata.Select("field_name LIKE 'f_name'");
```

`}`

Try this:

```
@foreach(var queryformdata = db.Query("SELECT * FROM document_data WHERE doc_id = @0", 1534)) {
    <input type="text" id="@queryformdata.field_name" name="@queryformdata.field_name" value="@queryformdata.field_data" />
}
```

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid doing a database call for each input field. There are over 100 fields on some of the forms and it seems like there should be a way to assign the data without making a separate call for each. Maybe I'm wrong though. Is the best way to just make multiple db requests?

Comment: This should only make one request to the DB.  It will loop through the results of the request and assign the data.